# Regex replace java comments

Tags: python

I am working on a project for parsing a java file with python.

The input to my program is:

```java
public class TestMax {
    /** Main method */
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

The expected output is:

```html
<span class="keyword">public</span> <span class="keyword">class</span> TestMax {
        <span class="comment">      /** Main method */</span>
        public <span class="keyword">static</span> <span class="keyword">void</span> main(String args[]){
                System.out.println("hello world");
        }
}
```

The actual output is:

```html
<span class="keyword">public</span> <span class="keyword">class</span> TestMax {
        /** <span class="comment">      /**</span> Main method */
        public <span class="keyword">static</span> <span class="keyword">void</span> main(String args[]){
                System.out.println("hello world");
        }
}
```

There is something amiss in this method:

```py
def print_html():
    """Print html"""
    text = txt_edit.get(1.0, tk.END)
    
    new_text=[]
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        line_text = []
        for word in line.split(" "):
            if word in keywords:
                line_text.append('<span class="keyword">'+word+'</span>')
            else:
                line_text.append(word)

            if re.search("\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*", word):
                line_text.append('<span class="comment">'+word+'</span>')

        new_text.append(' '.join(line_text))
    new_text = '\n'.join(new_text)
            
    print(new_text)
```

The issue is here:

```py
if re.search("\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*", word):
                line_text.append('<span class="comment">'+word+'</span>')
```

This is pretty close

```
def print_html():
    """Print html"""
    text = txt_edit.get(1.0, tk.END)
    # single line comment (\/\*.+\*\/)
    # multi-line line comment (\/*.+)|(.+*\/)
    regex = r"(\/\*.+\*\/)" 
    new_text = []
    enteredMatches = False
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        line_text = []

        matches = re.finditer(regex, line, re.MULTILINE)
        for word in line.split(" "):
            if word in keywords:
                line_text.append('<span class="keyword">' + word + '</span>')
            else:
                line_text.append(word)

        for match in matches:
            line_text.append('<span class="comment">' + match.group() + '</span>')
            enteredMatches = True

        if enteredMatches:
            enteredMatches = False
            new_text.append(' '.join(line_text))
            continue

        new_text.append(' '.join(line_text))
    new_text = '\n'.join(new_text)

    print(new_text)
```

The output comes out to

```
<span class="keyword">public</span> <span class="keyword">class</span> TestMax {
        /** TestMax */ <span class="comment">/** TestMax */</span>
        public <span class="keyword">static</span> <span class="keyword">void</span> main(String args[]){
                System.out.println("Hi");
        }
}
```

It's adding the comment line twice. Ideally, this should produce the expected output shown at the beginning of the program.

Comment: The `word` is splitted from line by spaces. You can't combine then only using regex on `word`.

Comment: Do you consider the comments can be multiline or inline? Then, why do you expect the heading spaces before comment starting(`/*`) should be within `span` element?

Comment: I'd get a Java parser. A regex is not the right tool for this.

Comment: @Robert do you know of a Java parser that can process the file and append the html as show above?

Comment: No, I don't know any tool for this, but I haven't looked into it. A web search is probably your best bet.

Comment: In your case, I think that the keywords within comments should not be replaced as a `<span class="keyword">`. And the comments have a sequence that starts with `/*` and end with `*/`. Then it is not a regular language, so you can't use regex for this. You should implement or get a parser for it.

Comment: @BoseongChoi do you have any good examples to start off of?

Comment: I don't know which python parser is good for java syntax. But you can implement it by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Please find the corrected code to get the output as expected:

```
def print_html():
    """Print html"""
    text = \
"public class TestMax {\n\
    /* First comment */\n\
    Second comment */\n\
    public static void main(String args[]){\n\
        System.out.println(\"hello world\");\n\
    }\n\
}"

    # single line comment (?:\/\*.+\*\/)
    # multi-line line comment (?:\/\*.+)|(?:.+\*\/)
    regex = r"(?:\/\*.+)|(?:.+\*\/)"
    new_text = []
    enteredMatches = False
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        line_text = []

        matches = re.finditer(regex, line, re.MULTILINE)

        for match in matches:
            line_text.append('<span class="comment">' + match.group() + '</span>')
            enteredMatches = True

        if enteredMatches:
            enteredMatches = False
            new_text.append(' '.join(line_text))
            continue

        for word in line.split(" "):
            if word in ['static', 'void', 'public', 'class']:
                line_text.append('<span class="keyword">' + word + '</span>')
            else:
                line_text.append(word)

        new_text.append(' '.join(line_text))
    new_text = '\n'.join(new_text)

    print(new_text)
```

Please bear with me on the enteredMatches workaround. I added it temporarily to make it work. But the main idea was to show you the Matches and Group part of the regex to give you an idea.

Comment: Will need to relook at the regex. Something like this might work: (\/\*.+)|(.+\*\/)

Comment: did you get `re.error: multiple repeat at position 11`?

Comment: nope. I have updated with the sample text i tried. I am also running this in python 3.7.

Comment: I tried with python 3.6.6 and 3.9 I get multiple repeat

Comment: updated the regex, please try again. https://www.online-python.com/NxJ9H8jY5C

Comment: @EvanGertis did this work for you?

Comment: @NavaneethSen works like a charm! Thank you

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if we you are happy with the solution? Thanks.